# Error when installing dm-mysql-adapter

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I am very new to Ruby . I installed DataMapper and I am trying to install dm-mysql-adapter-1.0.2 gem . But when I try to install , I get the below error . I am using ubuntu OS .

```
vinoth@vinoth-laptop:~/Downloads$ gem install dm-mysql-adapter-1.0.2 -- --with-mysql-                    lib=/usr/lib/mysql -- --with-mysql-conf=/usr/bin/mysql 
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /home/vinoth/gems and
/home/vinoth/gems/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /home/vinoth/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dm-mysql-adapter-1.0.2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql -- --with-mysql-     conf=/usr/bin/mysql
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  -  ........


Gem files will remain installed in /home/vinoth/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/do_mysql-0.10.2 for  inspection.
Results logged to /home/vinoth/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/do_mysql-0.10.2/ext/do_mysql/gem_make.out
```

Am I missing something ?

Additional information .

Ruby Version : ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
Gem Version : 1.3.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have mysql dev package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Should do the trick